# MongoDB: Server sockets closed after a few minutes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, amazon-web-services

I am working with multiple AWS intances connected to the same mongo database (inside Compose.io Elastic deployment) but I keep getting the error `server <url>:<port> sockets closed` after a few minutes. Can anyone give me any hint about what may be wrong with the connection code?

CONNECTION CODE

```
var url = "mongodb://<user>:<password>@<url1>:<port1>,<url2>:<port2>/<dbName>?replicaSet=<replicaSetName>"; 
var options = { 
    server : {"socketOptions.keepAlive": 1}, 
    replSet : { "replicaSet": <replicaSetName>, "socketOptions.keepAlive": 1 } 
}; 
MongoClient.connect(url, options, function(err, db) { ... });
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
Potentially unhandled rejection [2] MongoError: server <url>:<port> sockets closed 
at null. (/var/app/current/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:328:47) 
at g (events.js:199:16) 
at emit (events.js:110:17) 
at null. (/var/app/current/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:101:12) 
at g (events.js:199:16) 
at emit (events.js:110:17) 
at Socket. (/var/app/current/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:142:12) 
at Socket.g (events.js:199:16) 
at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17) 
at TCP.close (net.js:485:12)
```

Comment: Which type of AWS instance is being created here? It should stand to reason that if you just want it to "spin up on demand" then that really does not suit the requirements of a replica set now does it? Also "off-topic". [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com). Just because you have a node.js app, does not make this a programming question.

Comment: I am splitting a mongodb migration process into different instances that handle a section of the db data. Each instance connects to the same mongodb replica set database to both read and write the new migrated data. However, after a few minutes, all instances but one get their socket closed.

Comment: I believe I'm having a similar problem, did you happen to make any progress on this?

Comment: It was caused by several errors but the common denominator are slow queries to MongoDB like an unindexed query on a big collection, doing a sort on a cursor using an unindexed field or a count that takes too long to resolve. I had several of those as I was doing a big migration and reading most of the documents in my database. Make sure you use .explain() to analyze the queries that you are making